# I would like to know what this insect is please

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image: First thought this was a moth but Im sure it aint. Noted in the Brazilian atlantic rainforest area Oct 2017]

Noted on the side of a tree in the Brazilian Atlantic Rainforest in Oct 2017. About 3-4 cm long . Middle of a very hot day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a planthopper, order Hemiptera, suborder Auchenorhycha, Superfamily Fulgoroidea. It looks to be in the Genus *Phrictus*. Very similar to a picture I saw on the web of *Phrictus diadema*.